# IntegrationTest AddInMemoryCollection hierarchical configration structure

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to mock configuration values for integration test and my configuration structure is like this .

```
    "TransferSettings": [
    {
      "Name": "Example Name",
      "Source": {
        "Host": "example-host-name",
        "Type": "sampleType",
        "Options": {
          "Bucket": "example-bucket-name",
          "ConnectionData": {
            "Hosts": "example-source-host",
            "Username": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "Target": {
        "Host": "example-target-host",
        "Type": "sampleTargetType",
        "Options": {
          "Bucket": "example-target-bucket",
          "ConnectionData": {
            "Hosts": "example-target-host",
            "Username": "username",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I can mock configuration with ConfigurationBuilder in my unit test method like this

```
            var configSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Name", CreateFixture<string>() },
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Source:Host", "localhost"},
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Source:Type", "mssql"},
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Source:Options:Bucket", "example-bucket-name"},
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Source:Options:ConnectionData:Hosts", "example-source-host"},
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Target:Host", "example-target-host"},
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Target:Type", "sampleTargetType"},
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Target:Options:Bucket", "test-target-bucket"},
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Target:Options:ConnectionData:Hosts", "example-target-host"},
            { "TransferJobSettings:0:Target:Options:ConnectionData:Username", "username"},
        };
        
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(configSettings)
            .Build();
```

.However, I want to avoid constant string usage like "TransferJobSettings:0:Target:Host" and instead mock TransferJobSettings class to mock configuration values.I have tried to use  TransferJobSettings class and mock with sample values but t returned null when I want to get config value.